# Catch youtube embed video events in ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, youtube, ionic3

In my ionic app I have listed youtube embed videos as follows :

```
<iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="200" width="100%" [src]="video.url">
      </iframe>
```

the video.url is generated from the below function

```
generateVideoUrl(videoId) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId + "?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0");
  }
```

It works fine, but I also want to capture events like youtube video is paused, or ended, or started playing etc.
I tried to import this http://brandly.github.io/angular-youtube-embed/#/ and use it with my ionic3 app, but that gives error 'angular is not defined'. Ionic does use angular but may be it use it differently that angular not defined error is generated.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Why can't you use `html5` `video` tag?

Comment: @Sampath I want to use videos from youtube.

Comment: Hello, have you solved it? I have the same problem, I have an embedded Youtube video running fine, but I need the commands to stop or pause it if the user moves to another page. Any hint? @Sampath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use embedded youtube frames on your ionic app.You can use [**native Youtube Video Player plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/youtube-video-player/).

**Play Youtube Videos in a native Video Player on Android & iOS**

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/youtube-video-player

*.ts*

```
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player';

constructor(private youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer) { }

this.youtube.openVideo('myvideoid');
```

In app.module.ts, also "import" YoutubeVideoPlayer and add it into the "providers" section.

This is the [**Git repo**](https://github.com/ihadeed/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer). Please review this link for more instructions including adding a YouTube API key.

Comment: Thank you, but does the native player means it will open the video in youtube application?

Comment: It plays Youtube Videos in a native Video Player on Android & iOS.

Comment: Thank you so much Sampath, the video plays much better now, but my problem is still there, I can't fire a function when the video pause. Do you suggest anything for that ?

Comment: There is no such method on this native plugin.